# Why can't I duplicate to Projector?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, clone, xps

I have a Dell XPS L502x. I do my stuff pretty fine working with two monitors. But when I tested my projector, which is connected via an HDMI/HDMI cable ending on an adapter to M1-DA, I am able to extend displays, and show only one of them but I can not clone it, why?

I already heard about some people saying that this model don't allow this situation cause HDMI output is controlled by Nvidia, and instead I show use miniDisplay which is held by intel Graphics.

But I can't understand how it's possible to extend display and have both working with different views, and not being able of duplicating one.

If it true something that is not possible, I would be happy if someone take some time to explain why.

Comment: It's possibly due to resolution size. If the max resolution of the projector is lower than the desktop resolution it may flat out refuse to show anything. As for extending, the video output device should recognise the best resolution and automatically adjust to that.

Comment: The projector is 1024x768 and I think I already tried to change the resolution to almost all available options. But I'll try again anyway, thank you.